# What is the difference between stack and call stack

Tags: javascript, stack

I just wanted to ask you about difference between stack and call stack, if there is any. (JavaScript)
I know that stack is "part of the memory" and call stack basically call functions. Am I right?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The two have nothing in common. Well, sort of - a call *stack* is implemented using a *stack* but the two concepts are completely different. A stack is a data structure, while a call stack is what a program generates when invoking functions.

Comment: A stack and a call stack are fundamentally different things and are not directly related to each other. A call stack is a "stack" of calls in the order in which they were made. So if you invoke a function, the call stack would consist of every function that is invoked by the function you invoked. While a stack, in memory allocation terms, just contains method specific values that are short lived and references to other objects in the heap that are getting referred from the method.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800462/difference-between-a-stack-and-call-stack-in-multithreading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, a stack is a "last-in-first-out" data structure.

If it helps, you can just think of a stack of pancakes next to the stove: freshly cooked pancakes are thrown on top of the stack, and when a pancake is needed for someone's plate, they take whichever one is on top (so the last one into the stack is the first one that gets taken out.)

---

You can create a stack in your own code -- this could be simply an array where you only use the `.push` and `.pop` methods to manage its contents. For instance, you can simulate recursion using a stack (of called functions) and a loop.

A single thread of memory often uses a stack of functions. When a function is called, it goes to the stack, and if it in turn causes more functions, they go on top in the order in which they were called. Of course, these functions can add more functions to the stack. Whenever the current (top) function completes without calling any more functions, it leaves the stack, and the variables it declared generally become unavailable.

The stack size will fluctuate over time until eventually the stack is empty, when presumably the program is completed (or -- horrors! -- the stack's capacity is exceeded and the program crashes.)

---

You can find a couple more hints about call stacks in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), including the idea that "A call stack is used for several related purposes, but the main reason for having one is to keep track of the point to which each active subroutine should return control when it finishes executing."